# Processing Animation Troubles

Tags: java, animation, processing

I'm back with another Processing question. This time it's about animation. I'm trying to make a simple animation for my group's character sprite, but it's not working too well.

I tried to fix it by watching tutorials but they weren't helpful. Most of them were general animations that weren't for games (such as making circles float like bubbles or fall like balls) and the game-related tutorials were few and far in between. Most involved spritesheets, something we're not using, and the ones my friends and I watched and implemented didn't work either.

The animation is supposed to be a simple three-frame walk cycle. At the moment, the code is close to what we're trying to do, it's displaying the character, but the frames are overlapping instead of running an animation. Here is the code that is dedicated to the animation:

```java
public void keyPressed() {

  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      inMotion = true;
      System.out.println("Left");
      posX = posX - 5;
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      inMotion = true;
      posX = posX + 5;
      System.out.println("Right");
    } else {
      inMotion = false;
    }
  }
}

public void draw() {
  background(bg_game);
  fill(50, 10, 10, 150);
  if (inMotion) {
    //System.out.println("CHar is in motion");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      System.out.println(i);
      image(playerImages[i], posX, posY, width, height);
      if (!(i < 3)) {
        i=0; //restarts for loop
      }
    }
  } else {
    image(playerImages[1], posX, posY, width, height);
  }
}
```

If there's a better way for us to handle this, let us know!

Answer (score 0):

In Processing, the `draw()` block is run between each frame. The computer does something like this:

1. run contents of the `setup()` block
2. display the result on the screen
3. run the `draw()` block
4. display the result on the screen
5. repeat steps 3 and 4

So when you put the `for` loop inside of `draw()`, it does this:

- render the first walking frame
- render the second walking frame (on top of the first)
- render the third walking frame (on top of the others)
- display the result on the screen

This clearly displays all three frames simultaneously, without cycling between them on different frames. You might do something like this:

```
int motionFrameStart = 0;
float walkSpeed = 20;//number of frames in a full cycle of walking

public void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    motionFrameStart = frameCount;
    //... the rest of your keyPressed() code
  }
}

public void draw() {
  background(bg_game);
  fill(50, 10, 10, 150);
  if (inMotion) {
    image(playerImages[(playerImages.length/walkSpeed)*((frameCount - motionFrameStart)%walkSpeed)], posX, posY, width, height);
  } else {
    image(playerImages[1], posX, posY, width, height);
  }
}
```

In this version, when you press a key, the computer saves the frame when the walking started on, and then calculates which walking picture to use based on how many frames have been displayed since the button was pressed.